# Offsetting a table cell

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a 4x4 table of radiobuttons. In the first row (an extra row ABOVE the 4x4) I would like a button centered horizontally. I have tried colspan etc. but all still leave the radiobutton in a column like the others, and thus uncentered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/EJbny/

```
<table style='width:100%;' border=1>
<tr>
    <td colspan=4 style='text-align:center;'><input type='button' value='hello'></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory Table-less Answer:

```
<div>
    <div class="center"><input type='button' value='hello' /></div>
    <ul class="radioList">
        <li>
            <label for="radio1">
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" />
                Checkbox 1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="radio2">
                <input type="radio" id="radio2" />
                Checkbox 2</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="radio3">
                <input type="radio" id="radio3" />
                Checkbox 3</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="radio4">
                <input type="radio" id="radio4" />
                Checkbox 4</label>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>

.center { text-align:center; }
.radioList {
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
}
.radioList li {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Amudt/

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Just use CSS and the `text-align:center` rule on the top row. Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PF77G/)**.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```